# how to execute a method based on a string which contains its name

Tags: c#, delegates

I have an Object which contains several methods and outside of it I have a list of strings where each of the strings value is the name of the Method. I would like to Execute the the method based on the name. From expirience, in python it is deadly simple. In c# I assume that it should be done with delegates I suposse. Or with methodInvoking?
I wanted to ignore reflection on this one.

i python you can store methods as objects, because it is an object.

```
def a():
    return 1
def b():
    return 2
def c():
    return 3

l= [a,b,c]

for i in l:
    print i()
```

The output would be:

```
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
```

Comment: You can only do this with reflection. C# and Python are very different languages.

Comment: No other ways, I know if you ignore Reflection since C# is static language, not like Python which is dynamic language

Comment: Yep, the difference between interpreted and compiled. (ignoring JIT and reflection). Anybody, does Python allow function overloading?

Comment: ofcource it does. even much cooler stuff. like inheritance from multiple classes.

Comment: @user853710 please link the documentation. My search would indicate otherwise http://www.google.co.uk/#safe=active&biw=1234&bih=730&sclient=psy-ab&q=Python+function+overloading&oq=Python+function+overloading&gs_l=hp.3..0l2j0i22i30l2.530284.540550.2.541081.27.19.0.6.6.1.469.3751.0j5j5j3j2.15.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.QjTEeppSF40&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.d2k&fp=a78e1f8da93061e8

Comment: sorry mate. My bad. I got confused. I read overloading and thought about overriding.
it is actually not neccesarry if you use it  with the *args and **kargs atributes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore reflection, you can create a delegate for each method call and store in a Dictionary.

Heres how you do it:

```
var methods = new Dictionary<string, Action >() {
            {"Foo", () => Foo()},
            {"Moo", () => Moo()},
            {"Boo", () => Boo()}
        };

methods["Foo"].Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your Python example, you are not "[executing] a method based on a string which contains its name" but rather adding the method to a collection.

You can do basically the same thing as you are doing in Python in C#. Take a look at the [Func delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx).

```
class FuncExample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var funcs = new List<Func<int>> { a, b, c };

        foreach (var f in funcs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f());
        }
    }

    private static int a()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    private static int b()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    private static int c()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
1
2
3
```

If you need to execute a function based on its name as a string, [Uri-Abramson's answer to this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687507/2392683) is a good place to start, though you may want to reconsider not using reflection.